# finding data in Matlab for common dates among n arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 6 cross-sectional time series arrays with varying dates and about 99 assets. I want to create a new array with only common dates from all the six arrays. I tried using the following function which uses "ismember" which works well for 2 arrays, but i am unable to generalize it for n arrays.

```
idx = ismember(indexchg(:,1),equitychg (:,1))
finalmatrix = [indexchg(idx,1) indexchg(idx,2) equitychg(idx,2:end)]
```

Can someone suggest a way to generalize this. I am trying to use find function in Matlab to find asset and dates but that i guess will have to run a host of loops to arrange the data. Can anyone suggest an easier way

Comment: Have you tried using the [merge](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/merge.html) method: `merge(indexchg, equitychg , otherchgs, .... ,'DateSetMethod','Intersection')`

Comment: `idx` is indexing `indexchg` but you also pass it to `equitychg` in last line, doesn't seem right.

Comment: the dataset is form of double array so I can't use merge

Comment: is there a way to convert a double array to a financial time series object

Comment: If they're not financial time series objects, then I'd suggest you stick with your method and just use a loop. Maybe create a cell array to help you not have to keep typing out each different array name

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have sets `A`, `B`, `C` and want to find elements that occur in all of them, you can nest intersections.

It can be done like this:

```
mySet = intersect(intersect(A,B),C)
```

If you are a lazy typist, you can also check out the [`mintersect` File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6144-mintersect-multiple-set-intersection) that basically does just this. Then it can be done like this:

```
mySet = mintersect(A,B,C)
```